# C# wait an event from external SDK

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm coding a new program and I have to wait for an event.

In this piece of code I register the event:

```
requestor.ResultFrameReceived += ImageRequestResultFrameHandler_;
```

The event raised is the following:

```
private void ImageRequestResultFrameHandler_(uint requestId, AvgError error, IFrame frame)
{ 


}
```

The event `ResultFrameReceived` is loaded from an external compiled sdk.

I have tried the following:

```
    ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    MethodThatRegistersEvent();
    ewh.WaitOne();
```

The method `MethodThatRegistersEvent()` calls the method that register the event `ResultFrameReceived`.
When the method registered is invoked (`ImageRequestResultFrameHandler_`) at the end of code I call:            `ewh.Set();` for stop the waiters but it doesn't work.

I have a infinite loop and it seems that the event is never raised.

**UPDATE**

I try to explain better my situation.

In my desktop application I have to use an external compiled sdk. 
This external sdk use events for return to me something.

So, I register the event with the following code:

```
requestor.ResultFrameReceived += ImageRequestResultFrameHandler_;
```

All works fine but I would like transform this event in a call for return to me the value. 
Like:

```
String a = code();
```

This is not possibile now because the event is called after some times.

For due this I have to wait the even that writes a variable. 
There are any methods for wait this event ?

Many thanks,

Comment: You should probably rename that method.

Comment: @TomRedfern You're welcome -Internet

Comment: You're registering the handler, but are you doing anything that causes the event to be fired?

Comment: @Servy: From what I understand, the event is fired by the external SDK. They want to wait until it's fired.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, but presumably it fires when something happens.  If that something isn't happening, then the event isn't being fired, and his code won't stop waiting.  The problem could be with how he's waiting on the event, or it could just be that the event isn't firing due to how that external code is being used.

Comment: @Servy: Certainly the event not actually firing could be the problem. Either way, just hanging up waiting for an event feels wrong anyway. They should probably rethink what they are doing. The normal way to do something like this would involve disabling some or all of the UI (maybe throwing up a spinner animation) and then reenable it when the event fires.

Comment: @MattBurland There's no indication that there is a deskop-style UI.  It could be a console app, or code running on a web server.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're blocking the main thread with that WaitOne call and your library/classes/system/whatever is not actually able to schedule the handler ImageRequestResultFrameHandler_